TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith') in require-hook.js
I am new to next.js and running npm run dev but when I try that, it returns an error saying:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')
 at mod.require (C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\server\require-hook.js:62:17)

I checked the stacktrace and it results to this:
// This is a hack to make sure that if a user requires a Next.js module that wasn't bundled
// that needs to point to the rendering runtime version, it will point to the correct one.
// This can happen on `pages` when a user requires a dependency that uses next/image for example.
mod.prototype.require = function(request) {
    if (request.endsWith(".shared-runtime")) {
        return originalRequire.call(this, `next/dist/server/future/route-modules/pages/vendored/contexts/${path.basename(request, ".shared-runtime")}`);
    }
    return originalRequire.call(this, request);
};

What are the workarounds to fix this?
I modified it to  if (typeof request === 'string' && request.endsWith(".shared-runtime")) { but it results to another error:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
I expect it to run.
